# numpy.memmap (Python) equivalent in R?

Tags: python, r, memory

I'm dealing with a large binary data file (>10GB) that about 10mins to read in using readBin, but then I get stuck trying to coerce it to a matrix, presumably because my machine is running out of memory. When I use python, I'd use numpy.mmemap in a situation like this to keep my memory footprint down; is there any equivalent for R?

Comment: Maybe the **ff** package? Always a good idea to look at the [task views](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) as a starting point.

Comment: Can you give more details on this? What your data looks like? In any case, you can read each column and later put all together var = readBin(yourdata, character(), n=3)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
library(ff)
library(biglm)
data <- ffm("binarydata")
```

You can also select only parts of it, so saving your memory:

```
data <- ffm("binarydata", c("col1", "clo2", "col3"))
```